# How to capture environment after fork and exec in c?

Tags: c, environment-variables, exec, fork

I have a C function to do a fork and exec that will be called twice.

The first call executes a shell script (call it setenv.sh) which can be any kind of shell (bash/korn/c/perl etc) that will set environment variables. The envp array will be NULL for this call but the intent was that it will return a populated array based on environ from the child process after setenv.sh has run.

The second call will be a C or java program that needs a certain environment to run so for this call, the envp array will be the populated one returned from the first call.

```
int execute(char **args, int argc, char **envp)
{
  char *function = "execute";
  int status, i;
  pid_t p, pid;
  extern int errno;
  sigset_t mask, savemask;
  struct sigaction ignore, saveint, savequit;
  int fd[2];

  pipe(fd);

  sigemptyset(&ignore.sa_mask);
  ignore.sa_handler = SIG_IGN;
  ignore.sa_flags=0;

  sigaction(SIGINT, &ignore, &saveint);
  sigaction(SIGQUIT, &ignore, &savequit);

  sigemptyset(&mask);
  sigaddset(&mask, SIGCHLD);
  sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, &mask, &savemask);

  if ((pid=fork()) < 0) status = -1;

  if (pid ==0) {
    /* Child */
    close(fd[0]);
    sigaction(SIGINT, &saveint, (struct sigaction *) 0);
    sigaction(SIGQUIT, &savequit, (struct sigaction *) 0);
    sigprocmask(SIG_SETMASK, &savemask, (sigset_t *) 0);

    printf("Command Line Parameters\n");
    printf("-----------------------\n");
    for (i = 0; i < argc; i++) {
        printf("[%d]: %s\n", (i+1), args[i]);
    }

    if (execve(*args, args, envp) < 0)
    {
      sprintf(err_data,"Failed to execute %s", args[0]);
      perror(err_data);
      return(FAILED);
    }
    write(fd[1], &environ, sizeof(environ));
    close(fd[1]);
  }

  while (waitpid(pid, &status, 0) < 0) {
  if (errno != EINTR) {
       status = -1;
       break;
    }
  }  
  if (status==0) {
    read(fd[0], &envp, sizeof(envp));
  }
  close(fd[0]);

  sigaction(SIGINT, &saveint, (struct sigaction *) 0);
  sigaction(SIGQUIT, &savequit, (struct sigaction *) 0);
  sigprocmask(SIG_SETMASK, &savemask, (sigset_t *) 0);

  return(status);
}
```

This function is working fine without the pipe code to execute a real program passed in and i can also pass it a set of environment variables in an envp array and it runs in that environment fine.

However, in testing with the pipe included, i find after the exec of setenv.sh, the child process never executes the writing of environ to the pipe and the parent then just blocks on the read from pipe.

I understand why it doesnt work - because the exec of the shell script overwrites the original C code in the child.  The question is, is there a way to achieve the aim of running a shell script with exec and capturing the resulting ENVIRONMENT back in the parent (not the same as capturing stdin/stdout/stderr).  Assume you cannot change the contents of setenv.sh because it may be provided by a third party.

No need to nitpick over error handling etc.. , this is a work in progress so just after some inputs in how to achieve the aim.

An alternative i considered was parsing the setenv.sh script in the parent to obtain the variables into an array which can then be passed to the real program.  Problem with this is the setenv.sh script might contain if statement blocks and includes of other shell scripts so i really wanted to capture the environment at the end of the run of setenv.sh (by exec'ing it) and passing this back to the parent.

Any suggestions appreciated ?

Comment: There isn't much you can do - you want to fetch the environment that results after running the script, which means that the child process has terminated by then. The kernel doesn't store the environment of zombie processes, so there is no way you can fetch it. The best you can do is write a wrapper script as described in Art's answer.

Answer (score 4):

You basically can't solve this generally without using debugging facilities of your operating system and digging into the memory of your child process. Which basically requires you to do write half of a debugger.

The closest you can get with a third-party script is something like this. Let's say that the script is for /bin/bash. You write your own wrapper script like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

. setenv.sh

env >&3
```

Where 3 is the file descriptor number of your pipe. You can write equivalent scripts for other shells. The only reason this works though is because the "setenv.sh" script is executed inside your wrapper script without creating a child process. Environment variables can only be communicated to children of a process.

In a system I use at work we have environment variables that need to be unified between many different programs that come from various scripts, many of which we don't have any control over. The way we resolved that mess is that instead of environment variables we require those scripts to output "KEY=VALUE\n" lines and then import them into scripts, makefiles, etc. through simple scripts (if required). That's probably the best you can do.

Comment: Looks reasonable, but how exactly do you write a wrapper script without knowing the pipe's fd? It may be different on each execution (if the parent process opens and closes other files dynamically)

Comment: @FilipeGonçalves generate it on the fly. `FILE *tmp = fopen("/path/to/temporary/script", ...); fprintf(tmp, "#!/bin/bash\n. setenv.sh\nenv >&%d\n", fd[1]);` Didn't say it was pretty.

Comment: Yeah, pretty much. Either that, or create a named pipe with a known, agreed name and have the script write there. Neither approach is elegant, but I guess there's no choice.

Comment: Which is why I stopped doing horrible things like this. Often it's easier to redefine the problem (the second KEY=VALUE solution) rather than keep fighting to solve it.

Comment: Thanks guys - i had initially written a basic function that reads the setenv.sh and parses it to separate the key=value parts and then does variable expansion to substitute variables it has already read into it's envp array, but can see there are some omissions to that such as includes of other scripts and constructs like if then else which might affect the environment.

Comment: Just wondering how sourcing of a shell script works i.e. when you execute <dot> setenv.sh, that adds the variables to your current environment and whether there is a way to simulate that in C without the wrapper e.g. exec in the parent as then the fork will pass the environment to the child so can capture it before the exec in the child and pass it as envp ?

Answer (score -1):

You can use :

```
extern char **environ;
```

environ is defined as a global variable in the Glibc source file  posix/environ.c.

Comment: Yes - that is what i thought but how do i capture it in the parent when the child is executed in a different process ?  I'm using environ in the function but the child code is replaced by the shell script so the original program with my call to write environ to the pipe is no longer in memory and i think named pipes will have the same issue as i'm not executing my code - unless maybe rather than executing the shell script directly, i execute another copy of my code which fork/execs the shell script - but i still cant see how i capture the environment of the child after it has executed.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question *at all*. The question is about capturing a child process's environment upon termination, not about how to access the current process's environment.

Comment: Sorry i miss understood.